# wget for windows not working even though (I think) I set the path right (Win 8.1)

Tags: windows, command-line, wget

I installed *wget for windows* via its setup program.  It's installed at 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe`,
and I've edited the PATH to reflect this (ie added `;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe` to the path).  But when I try to run `wget` the computer doesn't recognise it.  Eg.

> ```
> C:\Users\t0p>wget --help
> 'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) very carefully.  Can anyone suggest what's wrong?  The *wget* version is 1.11.4 3.2.8.7 dating from 2008.  Do I need to get a more up-to-date version?  If so, where might I find it?  And how do I remove the older version to make way for the newer version?  Or am I going wrong in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Add the installation directory to `PATH`, not the path to `wget.exe` itself.
That is, add this to `PATH`:

```
;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
```

When you get an error message like this:

> ```
> 'blah' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

It means the shell could not find `blah` on `PATH`.
As a sanity check, you can always try to run a program with its absolute path, in this example:

```
C:
\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

go to the bin folder of wget manually and then type cmd it will automatically set the path for you.Then run wget.

Comment: A properly configured PATH makes this unnecessary.

Comment: @music2myear yeah thought for temporary.